# account type recommendation for minor beneficiaries of a trust (US)

Tags: united-states, investment-strategies, trusts, minor

As the trustee of a trust, I’m looking for suggestions as to how to make distributions to minor great-grandchildren. This is not a lot of money, but not trivial. I’m considering UTMA/UGMA/529b type account.

I plan on remaining as the trustee for the accounts. I’m leaning towards 529b since the kids seem to be on the path of going to school. My goal is what it would have been for their grandparents, i.e., that the money be used in a useful way, like education. The minor beneficiaries reside in Illinois.

If you have any links or suggestions, I’d appreciate it.

Comment: Having a son who only went to college for three semesters, and then joined the USAF, I'm disinclined towards suggesting a 529.  Why can't it stay in the trust until age 25?

Comment: I read through the trust. It lists ages for distributions, and refers to a "young person's trust". It does not list any particular investment. This answered some of my questions.

I agree that the 529B would be an incorrect “investment”.

Now I will have to decide between an online trust or going to a lawyer. I really don't want to use a lot of the general trust money to create a trust for this amount and that is pretty generic.

Comment: Note that a 529b is a type of "bucket", just as IRAs, 401(k)s and UGMA/UTMAs are types of "buckets", which don't define how you invest the money inside them.